# How can find this two sequence recursive relations?

Tags: recurrence-relations, binomial-coefficients

> Let $$D_{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n+j-1}\dfrac{\binom{2n-4}{j}}{n+j-1},E_{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{n+j-1}\dfrac{\binom{2n-4}{j}}{n+j}$$
>
> I want find $D_{n}$ and $E_{n}$ recursive relations,

I try take somedays,At present I only find following
$$\sum_{j=0}^{2n-4}(-1)^j\dfrac{\binom{2n-4}{j}}{n+j-1}=\dfrac{3n-4}{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{2n-4}(-1)^j\dfrac{\binom{2n-4}{j}}{n+j}$$
can you someone help find the recursive relation with $D_{n}$ and $E_{n}$?

I also post [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200240/how-can-find-this-two-sequence-recursive-relations)

Comment: Crossposted to mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/q/200240/

Comment: Yes,I have post it

Answer (score 1):

The series $D_{n}$ and $E_{n}$ are of the form
\begin{align}
D_{n} &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+j-1} \frac{\binom{2n-4}{j}}{n+j-1} \\
&= \frac{ \binom{2n-4}{n} }{ (2n-1) \Gamma(3n-4) } \, {}_{3}F_{2}(1, 4-n, 2n-1; n+1, 2n; 1) - (-1)^{n} \, \frac{\Gamma(n) \Gamma(2n-3)}{(n-1) \Gamma(3n-4)} 
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
E_{n} &= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{n+j-1} \frac{\binom{2n-4}{j}}{n+j} \\
&= \frac{1}{2n} \, \binom{2n-4}{n} \, {}_{3}F_{2}( 1, 4-n, 2n; n+1, 2n+1; 1) - (-1)^{n} \, \frac{\Gamma(n) \Gamma(2n-3)}{\Gamma(3n-3)}.
\end{align}
By using the recurrence relations from [Wolfram generalized hypergeometric Functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/17/01/01/) page an attempt can be made to make a recurrence relation for both $D_{n}$ and $E_{n}$.

Comment: Thank you,But we also have relation?